# Unable to remove kubernetes pods for nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I’m trying to set up a nginx ingress controller to help validate a configuration.  I’m trying to remove all the pieces and re-add the ingress controller to make sure everything I’ve documented works.  The Ingress is removed, the service is removed, and pods successfully delete but they come back.  The logs complain about the missing pieces I removed (backend-service, lb/service, ingress).  Thoughts?  Was I supposed to remove this in a different order?  --force has the same result.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way to cleanup a namespace is to supply `-n namespace` with `all --all`

```
kubectl delete all  --all -n ingress-nginx
```

Comment: It's weird why I can't stop it from docker-desktop and it keeps restarting.

Comment: That is probably the correct behavior. If you stop an instance another is started to bring it back up live again.

Comment: But should there be a way to stop it for good from the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.  I forgot I need to delete the deployment.  Duoh.

```
kubectl delete ingress ingress-nginx-nginx-ingress
kubectl delete deployment ingress-nginx-nginx-ingress
kubectl delete service ingress-nginx-nginx-ingress
```